# git sudo user access denied

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, git, permissions

In my ternimal when I run

```
git clone -q git@codebasehq.com:zzzz/yyyy/plat.git
```

I am able to clone the project but if I run

```
sudo git clone -q git@codebasehq.com:zzzz/yyyy/plat.git
```

and give the correct password I get

```
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

any idea why is this ?

Comment: To answer this probably more information than given here is needed. And why on earth would anyone run git under `sudo`?

Comment: I don't think it is a git issue. Your root account may have a ssh key that it tries and which causes the server to reject the ssh connection. Another explanation would be that password auth is disabled for Your root user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your **root** user just don't have the right **public key** in `/root/.ssh`.

Your **user** surely has one in `~/.ssh`, but root does not.

Comment: I am a newbie to linux. I am trying to deploy my rails app on the server. I am using a gem to deploy my app. As you said my root user doesnt have a key pair but I do have it and the gem automatically uses sudo on every command. Is there a work aroud for the problem. I dont have access to the root user ?

Comment: Copy the private key from your user to root eg (as user): `cd ; sudo cp .ssh/id_* /root/.ssh/`

Answer (score 4):

codebasehq uses public/private key pair for authentication, so when you sudo you're trying to auth with root's key pair, which isn't the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

I think its really simple.

When you run the **git clone** with sudo you run it under the root user. And i think your root user has no valid public key to clone the repo.

There are some methods to enable only the key authentification.